# Programmatically using CMD in C

Tags: c, windows

How can I simulate these calls inside a program?
Like say I want to find all the active connections. So I want to use netstat -a 
How could I use that without having to literally having a window open?

Answer (score 6):

Use CreateProcess, redirecting the output.

If the calling application is not a windows application there is no issue with a console window (because a console programming will, by default, inheirt its parent console).

If the calling application is a windows application, set the right options passed to CreateProcess to default the console window that will be created to hidden.

Answer (score 1):

There is `system()` library function you can use - I guess Windows has it as well because it is standard C function since C89.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the "/B" option of 'start' command.

cmd /C start "Title" /B netstat -i

I'm assuming popping console is your main problem, 
and you a strategy of collecting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Never use system() (not professional, crappy)
Use Win32 net apis .
See the source code of netstat.